# How to convert rational and decimal number strings to floats in python?

Tags: python, rational-numbers

How can I convert strings which can denote decimal or rational numbers to floats

```
>>> ["0.1234", "1/2"]
['0.1234', '1/2']
```

I'd want [0.1234, 0.5].

eval is what I was thinking but no luck:

```
>>> eval("1/2")
0
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd parse the string if conversion fails:

```
>>> def convert(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        num, denom = s.split('/')
        return float(num) / float(denom)
...

>>> convert("0.1234")
0.1234

>>> convert("1/2")
0.5
```

Generally using eval is a bad idea, since it's a security risk. *Especially* if the string being evaluated came from outside the system.

Comment: +1. eval is completely unnecessary in this case, and I'm glad somebody (other than me, of course) stuck up for what's right.

Comment: Eval is not a security risk unless your co-workers are malicious sociopaths.  You don't need it in this case, but it's no more a security risk than open source code itself.

Comment: Very good. The string is indeed from outside so I need to go safe (and try not to learn bad habits). I was hoping for not needing to parse it but this is not too bad and works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, using `eval` is potentially a security risk, and certainly a bad habit to get into.
(if you don't think it's as risky as `exec`, imagine `eval`ing something like: `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`)

However, if you have python 2.6 or up, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), for which the string provided:

> may only consist of the following
>   Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts,
>   booleans, and None.

Thus it should be quite safe :-)

Comment: How is it possible to eval something as malicious as the example without having coworkers who are seriously deranged?  Eval is no more a security risk than access to the shell is a security risk.

Comment: Fair point..If you're not dealing with untrusted input then eval is no risk. I think I'm influenced by this post: http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/#security -- PHP guys tried twice to solve their problems, before realising that they had to get rid of eval. So ...

Comment: ...I'm inclined to take the position that the easiest way to avoid problems is to get into the habit of using it never.  Then, if I do find myself needing eval, at least I've got the mental check of breaking one of my rules, which makes me look harder at what I'm doing.

Answer (score 7):

Another option (also only for 2.6 and up) is the `fractions` module.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction("0.1234")
Fraction(617, 5000)
>>> Fraction("1/2")
Fraction(1, 2)
>>> float(Fraction("0.1234"))
0.1234
>>> float(Fraction("1/2"))
0.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `from __future__ import division` to get the behavior you want. Then, in a pinch, you can do something like

```
from __future__ import division
strings = ["0.1234", "1/2", "2/3"]
numbers = map(eval, strings)
```

to get a list of floats out of your strings. If you want to do this the "right" way, don't use `eval()`, but instead write a function that accepts a string and calls `float()` on it if it contains no slash, or parses the string and divides the numerator and denominator if there's a slash in it.

One way to do it:

```
def parse_float_string(x)
    parts = x.split('/', 1)
    if len(parts) == 1:
        return float(x)
    elif len(parts) == 2:
        return float(parts[0])/float(parts[1])
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Then just `map(parse_float_string, strings)` will get you your list.

Answer (score 3):

The `/` operator does integer division. Try:

```
>>> eval("1.0*" + "1/2")
0.5
```

Because `eval()` is potentially dangerous, you should always check precisely what you are passing into it:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "1/2"
>>> if re.match(r"\d+/\d+$", s):
...     eval("1.0*" + s)
...
0.5
```

However, if you go to the trouble of matching the input against a regex in the first place, you might as well use `r"(\d+)/(\d+)$"` to extract the numerator and denominator, do the division yourself, and entirely avoid `eval()`:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\d+)/(\d+)$", s)
>>> if m:
...     float(m.group(1)) / float(m.group(2))
...
0.5
```

Comment: Thanks, the eval hint is nice to now and would do the job just great... except that I realized I need a safe solution as pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with eval is that, as in python, the quotient of integers is an integer. So, you have several choices.

The first is simply to make integer division return floats:

```
from __future__ import division
```

The other is to split the rational number:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(int, rat_str.split("/")), 1)
```

Where rat_str is the string with a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, this should work.

```
>>> x = ["0.1234", "1/2"]
>>> [eval(i) for i in x]
[0.1234, 0.5]
```

Comment: Right, in Python 3 they made `from __future__ import division` the default... in Python 3, the future is now!

Answer (score 1):

[sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) can help you out here:

```
import sympy

half = sympy.Rational('1/2')
p1234 = sympy.Rational('0.1234')
print '%f, %f" % (half, p1234)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because 1 and 2 are interpreted by Python as integers and not floats. It needs to be 1.0/2.0 or some mix of that.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions with `from __future__ import division` combined with `eval` will certainly work.

It's probably worth pointing out that the suggestions that don't use `eval` but rather parse the string do so because `eval` is dangerous: if there is some way for an arbitrary string to get sent to `eval`, then your system is vulnerable. So it's a bad habit. (But if this is just quick and dirty code, it's probably not *that* big a deal!)